# How do I install a ground for the transformer for my doorbell?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, transformer

I installed a Ring doorbell and it says I need a different transformer than what I have. My current one is attached to the bottom of my breaker box. The old one has no ground but the new one does. Can I just connect the ground to the bottom of the panel box? Also can I just cut the neutral and hot wire and wire nut to the new one inside the box?

Comment: Welcome to [diy.se], please take the [tour]. Please also [edit] your question to include a couple of clear, focused, well lit pics showing the wiring of the existing transformer. Also, include the make/model number of the new transformer. ProTip™: It's likely that the existing transformer _is_ grounded, simply by being attached directly to the panel. Your new one will _probably_ also be grounded this way, but we'd need the brand/model # to be sure.